# quick problem with regular expressions

Tags: php

I'm having trouble stripping this piece of HTML:

```
title="External Link" alt="External Link"/></h5>
                </a>


                This text is needed without the spaces..

            </div>
```

Here is the general method I attempted:

```
$array = array();
preg_match( '/<\/h5>(.*?)               
            /si', $data, $array ) ;
```

I just can't seem to crack it.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

**P.s** The text may also contain html tags itself, such as `<em> or <strong>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
preg_match('#</h5>\s*</a>\s*(\w.+)\s*</div>#Uis', $data, $array);
```

Comment: Perfect, but there is sometimes html styling inside the text area. Could i possibly check for that aswell? For example if a <em> tag appears.

Comment: If you need that styling too, so it will work. If you wanna grab text  to the styling(some html code), so change (\w.+) to (\w[^<>]+)\s*. Or if you need clear that styling after grabing, just use htmlspecialcharts($matchedText);